# Pointers for Character Array vs Integer Array in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to understand pointers and and arrays in C++. I've noticed that in the following code outputting `a` correctly gives the address of the first element in `array`, however outputting `c` gives `pk` rather than an address.

```
int array[3]={4,7,2};
int * a;

a= array;

char Carray[3]={'p','k','\0'};
char * c;

c= Carray;

cout << a << "\n";
cout << c << "\n";
```

Is this the incorrect way to find the address of the first element in `Carray`? Or is this some quirk of how `cout` interprets pointers for integer and character arrays.

Output:

```
Ox23fe30
pk
```

Comment: Please show us the output that you get from those statements.

Comment: C-style strings are `char` arrays ending in a null char `\0`, and `cout` is assuming you are passing it a C-style string. So your method of getting the address of first element is correct, but `cout`'s interpretation of that address is different for `int` and `char`.

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking for comparisons with C or something like that, don't tag your C++ questions with C - the languages and their idiomatic answers can be very different.

Answer (score 7):

It's a quirk of how `cout` interprets pointers for *character* arrays.

When given a pointer, `cout` will print the address, unless it is a `char*`, in which case it interprets the pointer as a c-style-string (pointer to an array of chars ending will a null byte).

To print the address of a char array, cast it to `void*` first: `cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(c) << "\n";`

Answer (score 5):

With `c`, you're calling `operator<<(std::istream&, char*)`.  That just prints the characters until it hits `'\0'`, like a regular old C-style string.

With `a`, `operator<<(std::istream&, int*)` prints the address.

Comment: Technically I think the overload is `operator<<(std::istream&, void*)`

Answer (score 1):

It is a "quirk" from C. In C, a string of characters is a null-terminated `char[]`. `cout` allows for using C-style strings, so it outputs the character pointer as if it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

`cout` interprets char pointers in different way than say int pointers, so your way of getting the address of the first array element is ok.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to char is generally treated as a NULL-terminated string in C and C++.  For an STL stream such as cout, a char pointer is definitely treated as a NULL-terminated string.